# How can I synchronize separate Tomboy notebooks between different Linux computers?

Tags: linux, sync, tomboy

How can I synchronize separate Tomboy notebooks between different Linux computers?

Let's say, Tomboy has two notebooks and one is synchronized with one computer, and the second notebook with another PC. Like I do not want to have my job notes on home computer.

Comment: why not just synchronize all 3 computers?

Comment: I do not want to have my job notes on home computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no supported way to sync only specific notebooks. It is a feature we hope to add in future versions of Tomboy.

For now, you would have to write your own solution.  Writing a Tomboy add-in would probably make the most sense, or if you are only on Linux you could write a Python script that accessed Tomboy through it's dbus interface.

Using Unison or another straight file syncing tool would not work, because Tomboy keeps all note files in the same directory, regardless of what notebook they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this using [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/). It's a two-way file and folder synchronizer. You'll just need to find out the exact path to each Tomboy notebook on each computer, and you'll need to establish a network connection between them, or use a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Ubuntu, then [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) (beta) [<strike>can</strike> *might* do it](https://one.ubuntu.com/features/#notes). (Given @Sandy's answer @jor's comment: I guess it's quite likely it will synchronize *all* notebooks though.)

(Standard on 9.10; [separate install](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/installation/) on 9.04 and later. It might even install on non-Ubuntu, but given the minimum version of 9.04 I doubt that.)

Comment: But does this allow synchronization of separate a 'notebook' and not all the notes in tomboy?

Comment: Good question, I might be wrong here...